# Adding all text input values into one total quantity box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something which seems simple enough but I can't get it to work. I'm still a novice at Java but I'm more interested in learning than paying someone to do it for me. So any help, guidance, would be much appreciated.

I have a form for a product

I have options set up with quantity amounts. (Small, Med, Large, XL)

All I need is for the main quantity box at the bottom to update it's value based on what the user inputs on the previous.

I've tried writing a simple script based on other post I've read

```
$("input.Qty").keyup(function(){
  sumValues();
});

function sumValues() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("input.Qty").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var amount = parseInt($this.val(), 1);
        sum += amount === "" || isNaN(amount)? 0 : amount;
    });

    $("#qtybox").text(sum);
}

$(function() {

  sumValues();

});
```

Based on everything I've read it seems the using the keyup method is easiest approach. Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: `parseInt($this.val(), 1);` looks incorrect. Did you mean `parseInt($this.val(), 10);` instead?

Comment: "novice at Java" >.< Java is not JavaScript. Even a novice should be aware of it.

Comment: @techfoobar, yes 10 was the correct value in my code.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is curious parseInt(<any integer>, 1) == NaN

Comment: Probably a good idea to read up on what [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) is if you're unsure about it :)

Comment: @ChrisNilghe thanks. It makes calculus look simple!

Answer (score 3):

```
parseInt($this.val(), 1);
                      ^---- You are using the wrong radix
```

supposed to be

```
parseInt($this.val(), 10);
```

The other issue might be that you are binding the event outside the `DOM` ready handler.
So there might be a possibility that the elements were still not available at the time the events were bound. Try moving to inside `DOM ready handler`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bSpra/1)**

```
$(function () {
    $("input.Qty").keyup(function () {
        sumValues();
    }).keyup();
});

function sumValues() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("input.Qty").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var amount = parseInt($this.val(), 10);
        sum += amount === "" || isNaN(amount) ? 0 : amount;
    });

    $("#qtybox").text(sum);
}
```

Comment: Ok, even with the change I didn't get an update.

Since each option has an specific ID could that possibly be a reason?

<input id="options_4131_2" class="checkbox  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option validation-passed" type="checkbox" value="21823" name="options[4131][]" onclick="optionSetQtyProduct.checkboxQty(this); dependentOptions.select(this);opConfig.reloadPrice();"></input>

Comment: `id` has nothing to do with it since, you are selecting them using a class.

Comment: Looks like your selector is wrong in the first place.. Your inputs have a class called `qty` and not `Qty` .. Selectors are case sensitive. `<input type="text" class="input-text qty  ` .. Change your selector to use `$('input.qty')` instead

Comment: It looks like you don't have the class "Qty" attached to your inputs. You need to have that in the class on your inputs for the selector to work properly. It's also best to use lower case for your classes. `<input type="text" id="options_4131_2" class="qty"></input>`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the fiddle also. I think I'm getting thrown off by class names. I found another script in my file that shows different values it seems. 

' if ($('options_'+optionId+'_qty')) {
                                var optionQty = parseInt($('options_'+optionId+'_qty').value);
                            } else if ($('options_'+optionId+'_'+el.value+'_qty')) {
                                var optionQty = parseInt($('options_'+optionId+'_'+el.value+'_qty').value);
                            } else {
                                var optionQty = 1; '

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumValues() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("input.Qty").each(function() {
        sum += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });

    $("#qtybox").text(sum);
}

$(function() {
    $("input.Qty").on('keyup', sumValues).trigger('keyup');
});
```